Why don't cosmologists consider that the universe has been expanding at a constant rate since the big bang?
The current rate of the expansion of the universe is equal to or very close to the average rate of its expansion since the moment of the big bang. The simplest explanation would seem to be that the universe has been expanding at this constant rate ever since the moment of the big bang.
I know the data of Perlmutter et al is said to demonstrate accelerating expansion but that is only correct for Euclidean space. If the universe has curvature, the data is fully consistant with constant expansion.

To be blunt: pretty sure those data correct for spacetime being non-Euclidean, since Euclidean space is non-expanding by definition. (It makes no sense to consider Euclidean spacetime since it is FLRW (a Lorentzian spacetime) that models expansion.) If those data are consistent with Euclidean space, then there’s no expansion (and also relativity doesn’t exist, which makes the data nonsensical in the first place).

I can assure you that no professional modern cosmologist believes the universe to be euclidean. Can you please give some material to back up the claims in your second paragraph?

In terms of the scale factor $a$, are you asking about the possibility $\dot{a}$ is constant, or that $\dot{a}/a$ is constant?

@controlgroup the OP says space is Euclidean, not spacetime. Space is indeed very close to being Euclidean (at least in the sense of not having curvature

I would argue that the difference between Euclidean and Lorentzian-Minkowski is the difference between our Universe and a completely-different one, though...

@controlgroup. My confusion - I should have said 'flat ie no curvature.'

@Paulina My confusion - I should have said 'flat ie no curvature.' As to an example - The FLRW curvature-only metric has a distance red shift relationship very close to the data of Perlmutter et al and has a constant expansion rate.

“No curvature” implies “no expansion”.

@controlgroup. But you can have zero curvature in the FLRW metric, as is the case for the standard model.

You can’t; the Riemann tensor has nonzero components $R_{iitt}=a\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 a}{\mathrm{d} t^2}$ among others. Unless $a$ is constant (implying no expansion) or zero (implying that all events are causally-disconnected; obviously not the case) these components are always nonzero and thus the metric is not conformally flat.

@controlgroup The universe has close to zero spatial curvature.and is expanding.

"Zero spatial curvature" is very different from "zero curvature", though. I'm sure we'll agree on that.

@controlgroup Neither the OP or the question seem confused about this. Your first comment however conflates the two; twice.

See previous comments by the OP: "you can have zero curvature in the FLRW metric" - "I should have said 'flat i.e. no curvature'" - the distinction is important.

@controlgroup. But the FLRW metric for the standard model, which is expanding, has zero curvature.

@J.G.  a˙ is constant, as it is in the FLRW curvature-only metric.

A $w=-1$ equation of state in cosmology corresponds to a dark energy-dominated Universe, which has scale factor $a\propto e^{Ht}$ by a solution to the Friedmann equations. That's the long and the short of it, given that that's the kind of DE we observe (due to cosmological constant).

@controlgroup. I don't think we observe dark energy at all. The standard model requires it. But in eg the curvature-only metric, also a solution to the Friedmann equations, w = -1/3 and the universe is expanding at a constant rate.


the SM doesn’t require DE, and 2) that doesn’t mean it wasn’t present, just that it didn’t dominate at that time.


I can't see why you think this would be the simplest explanation. A universe expanding at a constant rate would have to be empty, since the presence of matter slows the expansion. And if you measure how much matter there is, assume that this is the entire contents, then you end up with a universe that is slightly younger than the oldest things in it. Such a universe is open and not flat, and cannot be described as Euclidean.
Apart from the obvious point that the universe isn't empty, a constant expansion, empty, curvature-only universe also doesn't fit the supernova data.

The type Ia supernovae results and inferences do not assume that the universe is flat. On the contrary, a common view at the time of Perlmutter et al.'s initial work was that the universe had insufficient matter in it to be flat and was open as described above.
In fact, the first analyses of a handful of high redshift supernovae suggested that the the universe was not the $\Lambda$-dominated, flat concordance $\Lambda$CDM model of today. From the abstract of Perlmutter et al. (1997):

The results for Omega_Lambda-versus-Omega_M are inconsistent with Lambda-dominated, low density, flat cosmologies that have been proposed to reconcile the ages of globular cluster stars with higher Hubble constant values.

More data, improved techniques and better calibration of the low redshift sample meant that by 1998, a $\Lambda=0$ open universe was being ruled out. From Perlmutter et al. (1998):

An open, Λ=0 cosmology also does not fit the data well: the data indicate that the cosmological constant is nonzero and positive, with a confidence of P(Λ>0)=99%,

In other words, the possibility of non-flat universes always was (and continues to be) considered. In fact I don't think the supernova data alone put very tight constraints on the flatness of the universe. Big departures from flatness do appear to be ruled out by the supernova data when combined with corroborating information from the cosmic microwave background. That, and the fact that flatness is a prediction of inflationary models is why supernova datasets are often modelled in the context of a flat universe.

I've always been suspicious of the argument from the CMB power spectrum that the universe is flat. Surely the argument is circular? It takes the age of the universe at the period of recombination to be around 300,000 years. But this value is taken straight from the Lambda CDM model. The Lambda CDM model has been used to prove the  Lambda CDM model. In eg the FLRW curvature-only metric, the age of the universe at the period of recombination is around 13 million years. This slower pace in the early universe would be very welcome to those who study early galaxy formation.

@JohnHobson and as I said, that model is considered (green line) and rejected by the supernova data and by the obvious fact that the universe isn't empty. The age at recombination is not a parameter required to model the CMB.

Surely the size of the fluctuations at recombination is the speed of their growth, very close to the speed of light, times the age of the universe at recombination. I assume the 'empty' model is the FLRW curvature-only metric. Of course this does not have to be empty if the energies of the components sum to zero. - I have written a book on the curvature-only metric. It needs reviewing. Would you - or anyone else - be willing to do this. I could make some expenses available if that would help.
